# how do you disconnect an active user logged in to a box?

Tags: remote-desktop

how do you disconnect an active user logged in to a box? There should be a command line tool that comes with Windows, but I forgot it's name. It lists all the users logged in to a box and you can force disconnect of some, because, for example, you want to Remote Desktop to it and there's too many users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a combination of the `rwinsta` and `qwinsta` commands.

first do `qwinsta /SERVER:<server_name>` to get a list of session ids then do `rwinsta <session_id> /SERVER:<server_name>`

It should also be noted you can use the `/console` (rdp client < 6.0 i believe) or `/admin` (rdp client > 6.0 i believe) to get in onto session 0 or the console session which should allow you to kick people from the gui.